# block template for node view

Tags: views, blocks, theming

What should be the template for my block view if the url is

> block/manage/views/guides-block/configure?destination=node/9

I have tried `block--block--9.tpl.php` but does not work

Answer (score 1):

As per [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

**block--[region|[module|--delta]].tpl.php**
*base template: block.tpl.php*

> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from
>   the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most
>   specific template it finds:

```
block--module--delta.tpl.php
block--module.tpl.php
block--region.tpl.php
```